# Need help for Delphi multithreaded file writing

Tags: multithreading, file, delphi, io

I am writing a Delphi dll which calculates and writes the result to a CSV file. The calling program is multithreaded, so one problem is the simultaneous multiple writing to the file which causes the crash of the calling program. I tried to use the critical section to lock the file writing, but crashes still occur. If I configure the program to use only one thread, the problem disappears. Below is my code:

```
    library Question;

    uses
      SysUtils,
      Classes,
      Math,
      SyncObjs;

    {$R *.res}

    Var

        Outputfile: textfile;

        CriticalSection: TCriticalSection;

        CalNumb: integer = 0;

        PrintString: String;

    Threadvar

    Cal1, Cal2, Cal1Last: double;

    Function Calculator (input1, input2, input3, input4: double; 
    Factor: double; LastCal: Boolean; Print: integer): double stdcall;

    Const
        Divisor = 4;
    Var
        Temp: double;
    Begin

    Cal1Last:= Cal1;
    Cal1:= (input1+ input2+input3+ input4)/Divisor;
    Cal2:= (Cal1+Factor*Cal1Last)/2;
    Temp:= Cal2 - Cal1Last;

          If LastCal and (Print = 1) then
                begin

                  CriticalSection:= TCriticalSection.Create;
                  Try
                    Try
                      Inc(CalNumb);
                      Assign(Outputfile, 'C:\Calculator\Result.csv');
                      If FileExists('C:\Calculator\Result.csv') then 
                      Append(Outputfile) else rewrite (Outputfile);

                      If CalNumb = 1 then
                      begin
                        PrintString:= 'CalNumb' + ',' + 'Cal1' + ',' + 
                        'Cal1Last' + ',' + 'Cal2' + ',';

                        Writeln(Outputfile, PrintString);
                      end;


                      Writeln(Outputfile,
                      CalNumb, ',', Cal1:5:2, ',', Cal1Last:5:2, ',', Cal2:5:2, ',');


                    Finally
                      Close(Outputfile);
                    End;

                  Finally
                    CriticalSection.Free;
                  End;

                end;

    If Cal1 <> 0 then Calculator:= Temp/Cal1 else Calculator:= 0;

    End;

    Exports
           Calculator;

    begin
    end.
```

Are there any errors in my code? Multithread calculation and external file writing is essential for this project. Do you have any suggestion and comments? I am a beginner, so if you could post your code here, it will be a big help for me. Thank you very much in advance!
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Graymatter, thanks for your suggestion. After I make the changes you suggested, the application crashes before writing into the file. The previous version of dll can write certain lines of data into the file before the crash. In case I might make wrong changes, I post the changed part below. The other part of the code is not changed.

```
          If LastCal and (Print = 1) then
                begin

                  CriticalSection.Acquire;
                  Try
                    Try
                      Inc(CalNumb);
                      Assign(Outputfile, 'C:\Calculator\Result.csv');
                      If FileExists('C:\Calculator\Result.csv') then 
                      Append(Outputfile) else rewrite (Outputfile);

                      If CalNumb = 1 then
                      begin
                        PrintString:= 'CalNumb' + ',' + 'Cal1' + ',' + 
                        'Cal1Last' + ',' + 'Cal2' + ',';

                        Writeln(Outputfile, PrintString);
                      end;


                      Writeln(Outputfile,
                      CalNumb, ',', Cal1:5:2, ',', Cal1Last:5:2, ',', Cal2:5:2, ',');


                    Finally
                      Close(Outputfile);
                    End;

                  Finally
                    CriticalSection.Release;
                  End;

                end;

    If Cal1 <> 0 then Calculator:= Temp/Cal1 else Calculator:= 0;

    End;

    Exports
           Calculator;

    begin
    end.


    initialization
      CriticalSection := TCriticalSection.Create;
    finalization
      CriticalSection.Free;
    end;
```

Comment: have you log/debug your code, what line of your code causes the application crash?:

Comment: When I comment the block of file assign, append, and writeln, the application crash disappear.

Comment: It might be more efficient to write to a separate file in each thread and concatenate them into the final file after all threads are finished.

Comment: TOndrej, your suggestion is great. However, I can only modify the dll, and cannot modify the application. How can I modify the assign part so each thread can write into a different file? It seems I cannot put a variable into the file name or the path. I know it can be done via some complex way. Could you elaborate the details? Thanks!

Comment: As a beginner, you are biting off way more than you can chew. That much can be seen from the fact that you say you are multi-threading, but show nothing at all relating to threading. Where are these threads that you are creating?

Comment: @David Heffernan I didn't create threads in the dll. The calling application creates multiple threads. I configure the application so it can write intermediate data to a file, through which I find the application can call a dll and do a multithreaded calculation using the function of this dll. Because the application can only write limited types of intermediate data to a file, I tried to output other types of data through the dll. I know I need to learn more about delphi programming and I am doing that, but I need to solve this problem before the deadline so I ask for help.

Comment: I encourage you to ask a better question next time. Produce an MCVE next time. And please don't turn the question into an extended debugging session as happened here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creating a critical section object doesn't do any locking. You need to call `Acquire` to get the lock and `Release` to release the lock.

See [Using Critical Sections](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devwin32/threadsusingcriticalsections_xml.html) in the online help.

The problem is that the critical section needs to be created when the DLL is loaded so you will need to do something like this:

```
begin
  ...
  CriticalSection.Acquire;
  try
    ...
    // The code that needs to be locked goes inside here.
    // In your case it would be the code that opens the file
    // and appends the data.
    ...
  finally
    CriticalSection.Release;
  end;
  ...
end;
```

You will have to move your code into a separate unit so you can include `initialization` and `finalization` blocks. These blocks will get executed when the DLL is first loaded and when it's unloaded respectively.

Your new unit would look like this:

```
unit UnitForDLL;

interface

function Calculator(input1, input2, input3, input4: double; 
  Factor: double; LastCal: Boolean; Print: integer): double; stdcall;

implementation

uses
  SyncObjs, SysUtils;

var
  ...
  CriticalSection: TCriticalSection;
  ...

function Calculator(input1, input2, input3, input4: double; 
  Factor: double; LastCal: Boolean; Print: integer): double; stdcall;
begin
  ...
  CriticalSection.Acquire;
  try
    ...
    // The code that needs to be locked goes inside here.
    // In your case it would be the code that opens the file
    // and appends the data.
    ...
  finally
    CriticalSection.Release;
  end;
  ...
end;

initialization
  CriticalSection := TCriticalSection.Create;
finalization
  CriticalSection.Free;
end.
```

Once you have done that your project itself will be changed to a much simpler:

```
library Question;

uses
  SysUtils,
  Classes,
  UnitForDLL;

{$R *.res}

exports
       Calculator;

begin
end.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I make the changes you suggested, but the application still crashes, in a different way. Please see the updated question. Thanks!

Comment: @BF2015 You haven't included the initialization and finalization sections so it's crashing because you are accessing an object that hasn't been created yet.

Comment: @BF2015 I have updated the answer to give you some more insight into what you need to do.

Comment: @whosrdaddy That depends. If the threads are created in the host, and all functions call the same DLL, it's fine. But this question cannot be answered, and it doesn't help that as soon as one problem is fixed, the asker changes the question. The best tactic here is to down vote, close and delete the question, and train the asker to ask real questions.

Comment: @Graymatter Your updated answer works! Thank you so much for your great help!

Comment: @David Heffernan My question is real and specific. Graymatter quickly identified my mistakes and helped me solve this problem. I did not fully understand Graymatter's first answer at first and did not write the code correctly, but I did not change my question. If you don't like this question you can simply choose not to answer this question. Please do not "down vote, close and delete the question" to make those who need help helpless! Thank God, there are nice guys like Graymatter in this forum.

Comment: That's not how it happened. The question changed and started down a path of fixing one bug, and editing into the question the next bug. That's not what the site is about. You should have made the threading clear so that we did not have to guess where the threads came from. And you should have cut the code down to a simple MCVE. That's how to learn. Please accept the answer.

Comment: I certainly don't want you to be helpless. But down voting, close voting, and even deletion are tools to promote good question asking. If you ask better questions, you will learn more, and do so more quickly. Of course I want to help. If I did not why would I have written so many answers here? But it's important that the questions are of sufficient quality.